# Opening files using gedit on Centos

Tags: linux, shell, centos, gedit

I've installed gedit on my centos, when i'm trying to open a file using this commands:

```
gedit jenkins_build_dev2.xml
```

I'm getting an error :
cannot open display:
Run 'gedit --help' to see a full list of available command line options.
Any idea why ?

Comment: `gedit` is an X11 program. That error means you either aren't in such an environment or are running that as a user who doesn't have access to the display or simply don't have the DISPLAY variable set correctly (in some long-running session).

Comment: I've solved it, need to change the runlevel to 5 which is not so good here is the command
`init 5`

Comment: Yes, you need to have an X11 server running to use a graphical program like `gedit`.

Comment: I've already solved it using runlevel 5 it was set to 3

Comment: That happens to solve it because it runs the X server. The runlevel itself doesn't matter.